# ROC and AUC calculation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, machine-learning

Using Python 2.7 and here is my code to calculate ROC/AUC and I compare my results of tpr/fpr with threshold, it is the same result of whay scikit-learn returns.

My questions, (1) any ideas for improvements (especially for performance in my existing code) (2) any smart ideas to calculate of AUC?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics


def homeMadeROC(scores, targets):
    totalPositive = sum(targets)
    totalNegative = len(targets) - totalPositive
    sortedTargets = []
    tprs = []
    fprs = []

    # order by score desc, and get related target
    for (s,t) in sorted(zip(scores, targets), reverse=True):
        sortedTargets.append(t)
    sortedScores = sorted(scores, reverse=True)
    predictedTruePositiveSofar = 0
    predictedFalsePositiveSofar = 0

    for i in range(len(sortedScores)):
        if sortedTargets[i] == 1:
            predictedTruePositiveSofar += 1
        else:
            predictedFalsePositiveSofar += 1
        tprs.append(float(predictedTruePositiveSofar)/totalPositive)
        fprs.append(float(predictedFalsePositiveSofar)/totalNegative)

    print fprs
    print tprs
    print sortedScores

if __name__ == "__main__":

    y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
    pred = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, pred)
    print fpr
    print tpr
    print thresholds
    print metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)

    print "======"

    homeMadeROC([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8],[0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any machine learning, however, there are some ways your code can be improved.
[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is Python default style guide,
and so we use `lower_case_with_underscores` rather than `mixedCase` for most names.
The major exception to this is classes that use `CapitalizedWords`.

If we look at your variable names:

- `total_positive` is incorrect, it's the sum of targets, so could be called `total_targets`.
- `total_negative` is even more incorrect, it's the length minus the total.
- `sortedTargets` is correct.
- `tprs` seems like it means something well known, so it's a good name. Also the plural is great as it's a list.
- `predictedTruePositiveSofar` is long, instead I'd move this into it's own function and then use it once in a loop.

And so I don't like most of your names.
Try to pick good names, like `tprs`, for all your variables.
Naming is hard, so write a concise description of the variable in the context of the function.
But if that's too big, you may want to make a new function.

The code is mostly ok, but I'd move the initialization of your lists to where they are used.
I'd also change your two `sorted` calls to a single one with two `zip`s.
To do this you need to use the `*` operator, to expand a list to arguments.
Which is quite well [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/2044866).
But in short, `range(1, 10, 2)` is the same as `range(*[1, 10, 2])`.
This simplifies the creation of `sorted_scores` and `sorted_targets`.

After this I'd make a function `accumulate_truth`.
This will yield the amount of truthy and falsy values.
And so can move the `predicted_true_positive_so_far` into it's own known function.
As naming it something useful will be hard in the current context.
I'd also change this function to iterate through the list,
rather than through a range and index,
and to remove the `== 1` as that can change how the function works.
This is as `bool([1])` is `True`, *but* `[1] == 1` is `False`.
So your current implementation removes some truthy values.

To simplify the creation of `tprs` and `fprs` I'd change the creation of `total_positive` to be a float.
This changes `total_negative` to a float too, and makes all the items in `tprs` become floats too.
Alternately you can use [`__future__.division`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html).

Finally try not to merge printing and doing work in a single function.
Instead you should return `tprs` and `fprs`, and print them in the `__main__`.

This can result in:

```
from __future__ import division


def accumulate_truth(iterable):
    true = 0
    false = 0
    for i in iterable:
        if i:
            true += 1
        else:
            false += 1
        yield true, false


def home_made_ROC(scores, targets):
    total_targets = sum(targets)
    length_sub_targets = len(targets) - total_targets

    scores, targets = zip(*sorted(zip(scores, targets), reverse=True))
    tprs = []
    fprs = []
    for true, false in accumulate_truth(targets):
        tprs.append(true / total_targets)
        fprs.append(false / length_sub_targets)

    return tprs, fprs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tprs, fprs = home_made_ROC([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8], [0, 0, 1, 1])
    print tprs
    print fprs
```

Comment: BTW, another confusion is, I want to further improve code by import `print_function` from future module, but I am not sure how it impacts to my existing Python 2.7 code and how it facilitate migration (if I migrate to Python 3.0 in the future), I read here but feel lost (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/), it does not mention how future module works and not as clear as the future module document for division. If you could shed some lights, it will be great. :))

Comment: I ask future module print function since I tested for code in Python 2.7 `print 'hello', 'world'` it does not work (in Python 2.7) if I import print function from future module, so confused how much benefit I can get to use from future import print function? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but I think `__future__` is not backward compatible in `print_function` case, I tried `print 'hello', 'world'` does **not** work (in Python 2.7) if I import print function from future module.

Comment: In short, if not backward compatible, Joe, then what is the benefit of importing `print_function`?

Comment: Thanks Joe, what do you mean for both? I tried if I import future print_function, `print 'hello', 'world'` never works any more for Python 2.7? If I mis-understand your points?

Comment: Thanks Joe, everything is clear now.  Mark your reply as answer, thanks for the patience for helping.

Comment: BTW, Joe, it seems you write `print('hello', 'world')` twice in your above reply, do you mean something else or a typo? :)

Comment: Hi Joe, what is the difference between your first print style and your 2nd? As least code review display the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46398/discussion-between-joe-wallis-and-lin-ma).